# Synchronized attribute in different class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm trying to set up 2 threads who either increase or decrease an integer in another class. I'm having some problems with the synchronization of this attribute.

This is my main class where I set up my threads and counter class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Counter c = new Counter(10000000);
    Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(c);
    Runnable2 r2 = new Runnable2(c);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    System.out.println(t.getNumber());
    }
}
```

This is my counter class:

```
public class Counter{
private int number;
private static final Object countLock = new Object();

public Counter(int number){
    this.number= number;
}

public void increase(){
    synchronized(countLock){
        number++;
    }
}

public void decrease(){
    synchronized(countLock){
        number--;
    }
}

public int getNumber(){
    return number;
}

}
```

And this is my Thread1 class: (The runnable class is the same, just with 'implements Runnable' instead of 'extends Thread')

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread{
private Counter c;

public Thread1(Counter c){
    this.c = c;
}

public void run(){
    for(int i = 0; i < c.getNumber(); i++){
        c.increase();
    }
}
}
```

However, my output is always 10000000. Even though I synchronized both methods.
Is there someone who can explain what is going on?

Comment: You'll need to explain the desired outcome. Do you expect the `for` loop to finish?

Comment: @Bas Add `t1.join();   t2.join();` after you start them, so that threads complete their task before you doing a sysout. On a different note, I don't think the thread will ever come out of the loop as `c.getNumber()` keeps on increasing. I think you wanted `int number=c.getNumber(); for(int i = 0; i < number;  i++){` instead of `for(int i = 0; i < c.getNumber(); i++){`.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I realized what I did. The first thread increases 1 each time, and the second thread decreases 1 each time. I set the integer to 10000000 in the counter, and both threads use that number. I expected an outcome of 0, but I realized that that won't happen when I set the number to 10000000. Sorry guys, I'm just being stupid.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu you were right about that, thank you!

Comment: @Bas Glad that helped. Adding it as an answer in case you feel to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Add `t1.join(); t2.join();` after you start them, so that threads complete their task before the `main` thread executes sysout.

On a different note, I don't think the thread will ever come out of the `for loop` as `c.getNumber()` keeps on increasing.

I think you wanted to have

`int number=c.getNumber(); 
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {`

instead of

`for(int i = 0; i < c.getNumber(); i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, `System.out.println(t.getNumber());` is being executed before either of the threads gets spun up.

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: @Bas That depends on what you are trying to do. Do you want to wait until both threads haves finished? Do you want to let the threads run for a couple of seconds and then write the output? You'll need to explain the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this should actually never finish since you're increasing the value  you use as upper bound in your `for` loop in the same loop. Not sure if this is the desired behavior.

Second, your `System.out.println` will (most likely) always print the initial value used in `Counter` since the threads have not had time to do their work. For testing purposes you can add something like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);`. For a more sophisticated approach though, I'd suggest you take a look at `java.util.concurrent.Executors` and `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` (there are plenty of examples out there).

Third, your life will be a lot easier if you replace your `Counter`s `int number` with an `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.